# Gulp path wildcard for second part of a folder name?

Tags: gulp

With Gulp you can see wildcards in a path with `'src/**/*'`.

How can you set a wildcard for the second part of a folder name?

If I have these folders:

```
src/match-1
src/match-2
src/dont-match
```

How can I just match the first two? I tried this but it doesnt match anything:

`'src/match-**/*'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check @YOU's comment for the answer. Here's why it works:

In `**/*` doesn't just mean "wildcard!" It's saying

> in this directory or any subdirectory (`**`) match any file name (`*`)

(more strictly speaking, "in this directory or any non-symlinked subdirectory, add on any number or characters")

That's why you want `src/match-*` - the `*` does what I suspect you thought `**/*` did.

To familiarize yourself with globbing, read through @isaacs' [Glob Primer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer) and then write yourself some tests with the [globtester](http://www.globtester.com/)

Comment: Update: I now prefer Denis Malinochkin's glob testing tool, which supports multiple match strings https://codepen.io/mrmlnc/full/OXQjrZ/